# Get selected item name - Android ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, selecteditem

I have `ListView` which have items from a database.

My adapter is this:

```
    Cursor cur = myDb.getCategories();
    // Closing the cursor
    // DEPRECATED!!
    startManagingCursor(cur);

    // Set up mapping from cursor to view fields
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_ITEM_CAT };

    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.tvItemCat };

    // Create adapter to map columns of DB to elements on UI
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
                R.layout.category_layout, // Raw layout template
                cur, // Cursor (set of DB records)
                fromFieldNames, // DB column names
                toViewIDs // views ID to putt in list view
    );

    // Set the adapter for list view
    LVCat.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

**getCategories():**

```
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT " + KEY_ITEM_CAT + " as " + KEY_ITEM_ID
            + ", " + KEY_ITEM_CAT + " FROM " + ITEMS_TABLE_NAME, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }

    return c;
```

I want when i click on some item I should get item name. 
I've search and i found  **this code:**

```
public void onCatClick(){

    LVCat.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String category = LVCat.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
         // String category = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); --> This also I've tried, but the same result

            System.out.println("Cat: " + category);
        }
    });
}
```

For other people this works. But I don't get the item name i get something like this:
`System.out(23858): Cat: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4197f3a0`

So how can I get the selected item name?

Comment: Your setting the Cursor to the Adapter, and getting the Cursor while on selecting the listview item, Whats wrong with it, just cast category to Cursor and take the values from the cursor for category like `mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Column Name"))`.

Comment: Great, please up my flag if it's helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()` in your onItemClickListener to get item.

or use it

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvItemCat);

String value = tv.getText().toString();
```